# override for /layouts/joomla/content/full_image.php // alt attributes for images in Joomla 4

Tags: overrides, joomla-4.x, images

I need to make some adjustments to

```
/layouts/joomla/content/full_image.php
```

in Joomla 4.1.5.

For all (full) article images without an alt attribute the alt attribute should be the title of the article.

That works fine with adding the line

```
$item    = $displayData;
```

and replacing

```
'alt'      => empty($images->image_fulltext_alt) && empty($images->image_fulltext_alt_empty) ? false : $images->image_fulltext_alt,
```

with

```
'alt'      => $item->title,
```

Anyway, my challenge now is to only set the article title as an alt attribute in case I did not define an alt attribute in the article settings. I tried but I failed so far. But this should be an easy one, right?

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to solve it:

```
if(empty($images->image_fulltext_alt) && empty($images->image_fulltext_alt_empty))
{
$alt = $item->title;
}
else
{
$alt = $images->image_fulltext_alt;
}

[...]

$layoutAttr = [
    'src'      => $images->image_fulltext,
    'itemprop' => 'image',
    'alt'      => $alt,
];
```